# How can I avoid zoomout initially on tablets

Tags: android, css, html, viewport

I don't want to make responsive or so ..but I just want to show desktop view in tablets as well .. with perfect zoom

I have hardcoded some `div width 1080px`  so I don't want to write media queries..

I have also tried

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1 "/>`

but it shows the same results .

I just to show the same desktop view in tablet initially in portrait view

any viewport suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `user-scalable=no`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1 user-scalable=no"/>
```

Comment: initialy its zoomed .. when you zoom out it looks all fine .. will userscalable solve that

Comment: using `user-scalble=no` will not allow user to scale (zoomin/out)

Comment: but thats not solution. i want it to be zoomed at proper state

Comment: how much amount do you want it to scale initially? if its 2 times the original change `initial-scale=2` and accordingly. Also add `user-scalble=no` to disallow user to scale the site.

Comment: amount to scale cant be fixed. i am checking in ipads and galaxy tabs